# App to do something once back from SEND_TO

Tags: android, android-intent

I have app sharing data with `sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);`.
Is there a way to perform action once I am back in the app?
I am talking on something specific to the SEND_TO, or specific for interacting with other Apps.
In case there is no way to do it, I need to Override `void onResume()`. is there any other way?

Thanks

Comment: "Is there a way to perform action once I am back in the app?" -- not really, insofar as control may not return to your app for weeks. The user does not have to return directly to your app after you lead the user to another app via `ACTION_SEND`.

Comment: OK, thank you. I'll perform the action on the onResume with few "if" confitions..